# Assigning functions for different location classes

Tags: c++, template, inheritance

Suppose in a `School`, you can only study, teach, or walk; in a `Mall`, you can only purchase, walk, or sell;  `Outdoor`, you can only study or walk.  These actions are all functions that can be called, but we only want to make the appropriate functions callable in the different location types.  Here's my way of implementing this.  Opinions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

enum Option {Study, Teach, Purchase, Walk, Sell};

template <Option> struct ExecuteOption;

template <> 
struct ExecuteOption<Study> {
    static std::string optionName() {return "Study";}
    static void execute() {std::cout << "ExecuteOption<Study>::execute() called.\n";} 
};

template <> 
struct ExecuteOption<Teach> {
    static std::string optionName() {return "Teach";}
    static void execute() {std::cout << "ExecuteOption<Teach>::execute() called.\n";}
};

template <> 
struct ExecuteOption<Purchase> {
    static std::string optionName() {return "Purchase";}
    static void execute() {std::cout << "ExecuteOption<Purchase>::execute() called.\n";}
};

template <> 
struct ExecuteOption<Walk> {
    static std::string optionName() {return "Walk";}
    static void execute() {std::cout << "ExecuteOption<Walk>::execute() called.\n";}
};

template <> 
struct ExecuteOption<Sell> {
    static std::string optionName() {return "Sell";}
    static void execute() {std::cout << "ExecuteOption<Sell>::execute() called.\n";}
};


class Location {
    public:
        virtual Option chooseOption() const = 0;
        virtual void executeChoice (Option) = 0;
};

template <typename Derived>
class LocationCRTP : virtual public Location {
    virtual Option chooseOption() const override;
    virtual void executeChoice (Option choice) override {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->findAndExecuteChoice(choice);
    }
};

template <Option...> struct OptionsAllowed;

template <Option First, Option... Rest>
struct OptionsAllowed<First, Rest...> : OptionsAllowed<Rest...> {
    static void buildMenu (std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Option>>& menu) {
        menu.emplace_back(ExecuteOption<First>::optionName(), First);
        OptionsAllowed<Rest...>::buildMenu(menu);
    }
    static void findAndExecuteChoice (Option choice) {
        return (choice == First) ? ExecuteOption<First>::execute() :
            OptionsAllowed<Rest...>::findAndExecuteChoice(choice);
    }
};

template <>
struct OptionsAllowed<> {
    static void buildMenu (std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Option>>&) {}  // End of recursion.
    static void findAndExecuteChoice (Option) {std::cout << "Error!  End of recursion should not be reached.\n";}
};

using MostCommonOptionsAllowed = OptionsAllowed<Study, Teach, Walk>;

class School : public LocationCRTP<School>, public MostCommonOptionsAllowed {};

class Mall : public LocationCRTP<Mall>, public OptionsAllowed<Purchase, Walk, Sell> {};

class Outdoor : public LocationCRTP<Outdoor>, public OptionsAllowed<Study, Walk> {};

class Home : public LocationCRTP<School>, public MostCommonOptionsAllowed {};

class Cafetaria : public LocationCRTP<School>, public MostCommonOptionsAllowed {};

template <typename Derived>
Option LocationCRTP<Derived>::chooseOption() const {
    const Derived* derived = static_cast<const Derived*>(this);
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Option>> menu;
    derived->buildMenu(menu);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++)
        std::cout << i+1 << ". " << menu[i].first << '\n';
    std::cout << "Choose an option: ";
    std::size_t choice;
    std::cin >> choice;
    return menu[choice-1].second;
}

int main() {
    School school;
    Mall mall;
    Outdoor outdoor;
    Home home;
    Cafetaria cafetaria;
    Location* locations[] = {&school, &mall, &outdoor, &home, &cafetaria};
    for (Location* x : locations) {
        const Option choice = x->chooseOption();
        x->executeChoice(choice);
        std::cout << "------------------------\n";
    }
}
```

Possible output:

> ```
> 1. Study
> 2. Teach
> 3. Walk
> Choose an option: 2
> ExecuteOption<Teach>::execute() called.
> ------------------------
> 1. Purchase
> 2. Walk
> 3. Sell
> Choose an option: 3
> ExecuteOption<Sell>::execute() called.
> ------------------------
> 1. Study
> 2. Walk
> Choose an option: 2
> ExecuteOption<Walk>::execute() called.
> ------------------------
> 1. Study
> 2. Teach
> 3. Walk
> Choose an option: 1
> ExecuteOption<Study>::execute() called.
> ------------------------
> 1. Study
> 2. Teach
> 3. Walk
> Choose an option: 3
> ExecuteOption<Walk>::execute() called.
> ```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Is this a simplification of a more complex problem? For something as simple as what you've described, I don't think I'd use templates, and might not even use inheritance. But if it needs to grow in the future, then it might be worth it. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: It's a simplification of a more complex problem.  There will be many actions that a player can carry out depending on where he is, and most of these are shared by different Location derived classes, but various Location derived classes will not allow certain actions or have some unique actions.